# delete duplicate rows based on two columns after sorting columns

Tags: sql

I need to delete duplicate rows based on the values of the rows, that's after sorting the order of the columns.

I have a table with millions of rows, which I've filtered on just one 'File No_' to make it easier (I'll remove the filter eventually).

```sql
SELECT   TOP (100) PERCENT [File No_], [Line No_], [Created on]
FROM         dbo.[Shipment Serv_ Fin_ Status]
WHERE     ([File No_] = N'TA-P200081258')
ORDER BY [File No_], [Line No_] DESC, [Created on] DESC
```

This is the result of the query ([current results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVFHi.png))

| File No_ | Line No_ | Created on |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TA-P200081258 | 10000 | 2020-11-12 00:00:00.000 |
| TA-P200081258 | 30000 | 2020-11-12 00:00:00.000 |
| TA-P200081258 | 40000 | 2020-11-12 00:00:00.000 |
| TA-P200081258 | 50000 | 2020-11-12 00:00:00.000 |
| TA-P200081258 | 60000 | 2021-01-27 00:00:00.000 |
| TA-P200081258 | 70000 | 2021-01-27 00:00:00.000 |
| TA-P200081258 | 80000 | 2021-01-27 00:00:00.000 |
| TA-P200081258 | 90000 | 2021-01-27 00:00:00.000 |
| TA-P200081258 | 10000 | 2021-02-02 00:00:00.000 |
| TA-P200081258 | 20000 | 2021-02-02 00:00:00.000 |
| TA-P200081258 | 30000 | 2021-02-02 00:00:00.000 |
| TA-P200081258 | 40000 | 2021-02-02 00:00:00.000 |

But I want to eliminate the duplicates based on the 'File No_' and 'Line No_' columns (after sorting the order on the 3 columns).

So this is what the result should look like ([desired results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iswxK.png)):

| File No_ | Line No_ | Created on |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TA-P200081258 | 10000 | 2020-11-12 00:00:00.000 |
| TA-P200081258 | 30000 | 2020-11-12 00:00:00.000 |
| TA-P200081258 | 40000 | 2020-11-12 00:00:00.000 |
| TA-P200081258 | 50000 | 2020-11-12 00:00:00.000 |
| TA-P200081258 | 60000 | 2021-01-27 00:00:00.000 |
| TA-P200081258 | 70000 | 2021-01-27 00:00:00.000 |
| TA-P200081258 | 80000 | 2021-01-27 00:00:00.000 |
| TA-P200081258 | 90000 | 2021-01-27 00:00:00.000 |
| TA-P200081258 | 20000 | 2021-02-02 00:00:00.000 |

Can someone please help?

Comment: As SQL is usually agnostic to roworder, try to formulate your task more about the filters than the order. Maybe you find a solution yourself.

In the end you want to keep the earliest recorded Line_No of each file.

Comment: Please declare your RDBMS and version. Looks like SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot say, I understood you fully correctly but lets say you have data as first picture, and you want to achieve result in second picture, in that case, as I see, created on column doesnt have too much emphasize, then you can simply

group by for line_no, file_no and find min/max or etc grouping function for created on column if it is same for each line_no,

```
SELECT
  file_no,
  line_no,
  MAX(created_on) AS created_on
FROM
  test
GROUP BY
  file_no, line_no

ORDER BY 
 file_no, line_no DESC, created_on DESC;
```

it will provide you with desired result.

Comment: Please provide more info about your request.

Comment: Hi Murad,
Thanks for your response.

I've applied your solution like this:

SELECT   TOP (100) PERCENT [File No_], [Line No_], MAX([Created on]) AS created_on
FROM         dbo.[Shipment Serv_ Fin_ Status]
GROUP BY [File No_], [Line No_]
ORDER BY [File No_], [Line No_] DESC, created_on DESC

But it returns endless duplicate rows.

Comment: endless duplicate rows? doesnt make sense, this logic is that, if it will provide 1 maximum created on of each combination for file_no and line_no, did you check for one example?

WHERE     ([File No_] = N'TA-P200081258')

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to delete the duplicate which is the latest one (based on `Created on`).

You can use the `EXISTS` clause as follows:

```
delete from your_table t
where exists (select * from your_table tt
                where tt.file_no = t.file_no 
                  and tt.line_no = t.line_no
                  and t.created_on > tt.created_on)
```

Comment: Hi there,
Thanks for your response.
Actually, i want to filter out the duplicate lines with the oldest date.
In any case, i can't get your solution to work. Can you please help?

Comment: That's a trianglular join and it's going to be very slow. Window functions on an updatable CTE would be better

Answer (score 0):

You can use an updatable CTE with row-numbering.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [File No_], [Line No_] ORDER BY [Created on] DESC)
    FROM dbo.[Shipment Serv_ Fin_ Status] s
)
DELETE cte
WHERE rn > 1;
```